# Nested quantifiers: Is my answer right?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I need to express this proposition using predicates and quantifiers

*There is a person who loves no one beside him*

where $Q(x,y)$ = $x$ loves $y$.

And domain of $x$ and $y$ consists of all people.

Here is my answer:

$\exists x(Q(x,x) \land \forall y((y \neq x) \rightarrow \lnot Q(x,y)))$

Is this right?

Comment: No, there is a paranthesis missing :P Other than that, it looks right.

Comment: Ha Ha... Thank you Nurator . And Thank You  Oernik for editing.

Comment: Thank you Mauro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is right, but I prefer the elegant
$$ \exists x \forall y \big(Q(x, y) \leftrightarrow (x = y)\big)$$

Comment: Thank you Olivier

Comment: @rtawhidur You're welcome. Please click on "accept the answer " if the answer suits you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct.

I don't know you edited your post, but for now there is also no parenthesis missing.

(note that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is two formula then $\lnot\varphi$,$\forall x\varphi$,$\exists x\varphi$,$(\varphi\land\psi)$,$(\varphi\lor\psi)$,($\varphi\rightarrow\psi$) are well-written formulas as well)

You can also write without arrows :

$\exists x(Q(x,x)\land\forall y(\lnot Q (x,y)\lor y=x))$

Comment: Thank you An. Can you please explain this part ∀y(¬Q(x,y)∨y=x)?

Comment: $(\varphi\rightarrow\psi)$ can be defined as $(\lnot\varphi\lor\psi)$. As you can see from your construction, $(\lnot y=x\rightarrow \lnot Q(x,y))\equiv (Q(x,y)\rightarrow y=x)\equiv (\lnot Q(x,y)\lor y=x)$ And the first equivalence coming from contrapositive.

Comment: Oh yes. I see... Thanks for your explanation